# Verify Cryptographic Authenticity after Downloading Releases (Signatures)

Tags: security, installation

How can I verify the authenticity of a wordpress release after downloading it?

I tried to securely download wordpress today, but I didn’t find any information on the page about how I can verify that it’s authentic

- https://wordpress.org/download/

My understanding is that [wordpress started cryptographically signing their releases in 2019](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39309#comment:87), but I haven’t found any documentation describing how users can verify the authenticity of wordpress releases after downloading it, and the above page doesn’t provide any such information.

How can I verify the authenticity of a wordpress release after downloading it and before installing it?

Comment: See also https://wordpress.org/support/topic/verify-cryptographic-authenticity-afte-downloading-releases-signatures